# Undefined control sequence in algorithmicx package

Tags: algorithmicx

I use algorithmicx package, but `\gt` cannot be recognized. I cannot figure it out. If I change `\gt` to `\not =`, it works. But why does  `\gt` not work?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12rt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Question 1}
\label{sanv1}
\small
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{$m\gt0$}
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> $m\gt 
                 0$
l.11 \While{$m\gt0$}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\gt` is a mathjax macro, not a default latex macro. You could either define it yourself or simply use `>`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12rt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Question 1}
\label{sanv1}
\small
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{$m>0$}
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]